# In JSON Schema how are conflicting 'additionalProperties' to be parsed?

Tags: json, jsonschema

In JSON Schema if we have "additionalProperties":false at the root level and "additionalProperties":true nested how are we to resolve this putative "conflict"

For example

```
{
"id": "someId",
"type": "object",
"additionalProperties": false,
"properties": {
    "storage": {
        "type": "object",
        "additionalProperties": true
        "properties": {
            "type": { "enum": [ "disk" ] },
            "device": {
                "type": "string",
                "pattern": "^/dev/[^/]+(/[^/]+)*$"
            }
        },
        "required": [ "type", "device" ]
    }
}
```

}

Does one override the other?

Answer (score 3):

They don't override. Their scope is limited to the JSON schema level.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand - are you saying they are scoped to their individual levels and don't "overlap"?

Comment: Yes, as you say. Sorry if my answer was confusing. They are scoped to their individual levels.

Comment: Thanks I'll leave this open for a few days before choosing the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

JSON Schema is a constraint system, so you can only add constraints, never remove them.  If `"additionalProperties": true` and `"additionalProperties": false` both apply, the effect is just as if only `false` were present (because it is the stricter constraint).

Furthermore, `additionalProperties` only "knows" about `properties` and `patternProperties` within the same schema object.  It cannot "see" into subschemas (inlined or referenced).  So your schema above will not allow any properties.

Note that a similar keyword that can "see" into subschemas is likely to be added in draft-08, although we haven't figured out exactly how it would work.  Currently, no JSON Schema keyword behaves in that manner so adding such a feature is a complex endeavor.  But it's the primary goal of draft-08.

Comment: I am really looking into this new keyword. Having to specify `"additionalProperties": false` everywhere to prevent "over-posting" is kind of a huge pain. Can you update your answer with a reference to an issue or whatever when a way to track this evolution becomes available? Draft-08 is on its way so I assume this may already exist somewhere :)